# Mysql database modeling from Linux

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have mySQL database that I see form my Ubuntu shell, I want to run some modeling tool so that I can visualize the relationships

Please let me know how can I do that

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql puts out a free program [mysql workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Power*Architect and I like it a lot. I like it better than MySQL workbench.